# onPreviewFrame returns skewed YUV data

Tags: java, android, android-camera

All right, I'm at my wit's end.  I'm writing a droid app that receives preview data, processes it, and then displays the altered data to the screen.  So far so good -- except for the fact that after some indeterminate amount of time (usually a minute or two) the YUV data that comes in during the onPreviewFrame callback is...rolled...horizontally.  I captured the raw yuv to the sd card:

[looks like I can't post pictures here yet, so here's the url: [raw yuv capture](http://postimage.org/image/1vnnyy04/)]

This is my first droid app, but I've spent a lot of time working on various desktop video software.  The thing that immediately came to mind when I saw this was that I had a thread synchronization problem, and the buffer was getting overwritten in some strange way because of it.

And my code *did* use a worker thread initially.  So to eliminate this possibility that the issue was thread-releated, I took the worker thread out and put everything inside of onPreviewFrame.  Again, the same problem: skewed YUV data.

Then I did some googling and discovered that heavy processing inside of onPreviewFrame could result in random weirdness.  To circumvent *that*, I changed my callback to the OneShot variety, which resulted in the code I'm using now:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
            try
            {             
                Bitmap bmp = processFrame(data);
                if (bmp != null) {

                    if (canvas != null) {
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (canvas.getWidth() - getFrameWidth()) / 2, (canvas.getHeight() - getFrameHeight()) / 2, null);                           
                    }
                    bmp.recycle();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, I still get the skewed yuv data.

My testing device is an HTC EVO 4G.  I know this phone has its issues, but I'm wary to chalk this up to a hardware bug just yet, mainly because I'm almost certain it's due to programmer error.  Problem is, I've pared my code down to the bone, and the problem is still manifesting.

Has anybody encountered this before?

Comment: Have you tried it without your `processFrame`, instead just convert the YUV to a bitmap and draw it? Does the distortion still occur? How are you converting the YUV, using the `YuvImage` class? I've seen similar distortion when accidentally switching the width and height on conversion.

Comment: Ah yes, should have mentioned that.  I _have_ tried it without `processFrame`, and the problem still occurs.  I've tried two different ways of converting the yuv.(1) the opencv `Imgproc.cvtColor` function (I'm working from an opencv sample) (2) a pure Java implementation of the yuv<->rgb forumula.  I didn't know about `YuvImage`.  I can give that a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it looks like it's an issue with HTC phones.  [This](http://www.htcdesireforum.com/htc-desire-troubleshooting/htc-desire-%27purple-camera-screen%27/) is the exact problem I'm having.  [Over here](http://androidforums.com/evo-4g-support-troubleshooting/152727-evo-camera-not-working.html) they say it's caused by the rear camera lens coming loose and the solution is to push it in hard with your thumb for a few seconds to reseat it.

Not a software problem after all.